# Work permit for spouse of EU Blue card holder in Luxembourg

Tags: blue-card, luxembourg

My wife will be joining a company for work in Luxembourg soon and she will get an EU Blue Card. I will also be applying for a residence permit and assume that I will also qualify for a blue card by virtue of being the spouse. Will I need a work permit to be sponsored by a future employer in Luxembourg or will the features and benefits of a blue card suffice for me? Are there any other limitations for me to work as well?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Carrying out an ancillary activity as a third-country national family member of a third-country national](https://guichet.public.lu/en/citoyens/immigration/plus-3-mois/ressortissant-tiers/membre-famille/exercice-activite-accessoire.html):

> Third-country nationals holding a residence permit for **family members**, who wish to carry out a salaried activity on an ancillary basis **must apply for a work permit before starting work**.

Additionally, from the same page:

> Family members who have been resident in Luxembourg for **less than one year** when the application is submitted will be **subject to the labour market test**
>
> ...
>
> Third-country nationals who have been resident in Luxembourg for **more than one year** when the application is submitted will **not be subject to the labour market test**.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on [www.eu-bluecard.com](http://www.eu-bluecard.com/faq/):

> Spouses of residence permit holders or EU Blue Card holders are entitled to the same permit as their spouses without exception.

So it seems that your assumption is correct in that you will qualify for a blue card by virtue of being a spouse. I'm assuming that the same restrictions due to nationality are waived in that case.

Answer (score 1):

That is for residence only and does not cover employment

Comment: Could you provide a source?

Answer (score 0):

A "theoretical" answer had been given earlier, here are practical steps which you can do to obtain a work permit:

- Visit ADEM (Agence pour le développement de l'emploi - National Employment Agency) and ask for an appointment to register there. The office is here: [10, rue Bender, 1229 Luxembourg](https://www.google.com/maps/place/ADEM+-+Agence+pour+le+d%C3%A9veloppement+de+l'emploi/@49.603407,6.1346581,17.17z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sadem!3m4!1s0x0:0xe142c5f32ef38e2e!8m2!3d49.6034615!4d6.1351146). Two years ago, when I did this, there was about a month to wait for the first appointment.
- On the next visit, ADEM officer will explain your next steps and you will get the next appointment (again a month to wait).
- On the third visit, you will get access to ADEM's employment site. It is a typical job board, where you can have your profile, CV, apply for vacations, etc.
- After that, you have to visit ADEM every month and make reports what you have done to find a job.
- Also, you will have an additional appointment with an officer who is responsible for your profession. It will be in another office, depending on your profession. I am a programmer, IT jobs are managed by the office in [19, rue de Bitbourg, 1273 Luxembourg](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Agence+pour+le+D%C3%A9veloppement+de+l'Emploi/@49.6196448,6.1718934,14.12z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sadem!3m4!1s0x0:0x9997c345e4a112b0!8m2!3d49.614158!4d6.1710119). I don't know about other professions.

Note, that a work in Luxembourg requires fluent French, sometimes - German. IT jobs sometimes don't require French, but it is only about half of them.

Also, you may need to [recognize your diploma](https://guichet.public.lu/en/citoyens/travail-emploi/activite-professionnelle/prealables-vie-professionnelle/reconnaissance-etudes.html) (depending on where you got it). It could be done here: [18-20, montée de la Pétrusse](https://www.google.com/maps/place/18+Mont%C3%A9e+de+la+Petrusse,+2327+Luxembourg/@49.6052961,6.1332468,17z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x479548ce0a40ca65:0x3f0492866ab5c477!2s18+Mont%C3%A9e+de+la+Petrusse,+2327+Luxembourg!3b1!8m2!3d49.6052961!4d6.1354355!3m4!1s0x479548ce0a40ca65:0x3f0492866ab5c477!8m2!3d49.6052961!4d6.1354355).

The employer (of course, if you find any) will prepare documents for your work permit. It will take about 2 - 3 weeks if your salary is more than 60000 euro per year and about two months if the salary is less.